# area y perimetro de circulo en javascript

Tags: javascript, matemáticas

estoy empezando a aprender javascript y tengo un ejercicio que me piden que realize una función llamada perimetro que diga el perímetro de un círculo cuando le de el radio como parámetro. Luego otra función llamada  area que dé el area de un círculo cuando reciba el radio como parámetro.

esto fue lo que me sale hasta el momento

```
function perimetro(numero1, numero2, numero3){
   return 3.14 * radio * 2;
}
function area(numero4, numero5, numero6){
   var resultadoDeArea = perimetro(numero4, numero5, numero6);
   return resultadoDeArea = 3.14 * radio * radio;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript como muchos otros lenguaje incluye un módulo de funciones matemáticas para cálculos comunes entre ellos el cálculo de PI, mediante:

**Solución para la primer funcion**

```
Math.PI
```

Que desde la consola te daría:

> 3.141592653589793

Entonces para tu primer función puedes modificar la cantidad de parámtros que la función espera quedando así:

```
function perimetro(radio){
   return Math.PI * radio * 2;
}
```

E invocándola de esta forma:

```
console.log(perimetro(4))
```

**Solución para la segunda funcion**

Para el caso del área sería lo mismo mencionado anteriormente quedando así:

```
function area(radio){
   return Math.PI * radio ** 2
}


console.log(area(4))
```

Entonces:

- El valor de PI se lo dejamos al lenguaje
- El valor 2 es constante es decir dentro de la estrctura de la fórmula ese valor no cambia por tanto esta demás pedirlo en una variable
- Limitas a un solo parámetro y un solo argumento pasado a cada una de las 2 funciones
- Para el cálculo de la potencia usamos la sintaxis de **`base ** potencia`**
- [Aquí puedes leer mas sobre `Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/PI)